# Show that the set of n dimensional matrices, where its components belong to a ring, is also a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Where can I start? 
Can I prove for $2x2$ matrices and then prove the general statement using induction ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about including induction. The examiner is more likely interested on if you know what a ring is or not. The fact that you don't know how to identify a set with operations as a ring or not is telling. What are you having trouble with?  Do you know what the addition and multiplication operations are for the ring?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a great idea to prove it for $2\times 2$ matrices first. However, there is no need for (explicit) induction. The general $n\times n$ proof is basically the same, only you use $\cdots$ a lot.